# Execute Vuex action before initial routing

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I have setup Vuex and Vue Router. I want to show a setup page, in case a users account isn't properly setup. This is implemented by making an API call to the backend. The result is stored inside Vuex and accessed using a getter. The action is dispatched in `beforeCreate` in the root Vuex instance:

```
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App),

  beforeCreate() {
    this.$store.dispatch("config/get");
  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

However, my router `beforeEach` never receives `true` but the getter is definitely returning `true` as per DevTools:

```
router.beforeEach((to, next) => {
  if (!to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresSetup)) {
    next();
    return;
  }

  if (!store.getters["config/isConfigured"]) { // Executed every time.
    next("/setup");
    return;
  }

  next();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Delaying app load

It's not possible to use a lifecycle hook to delay loading even if the hook is marked `async` and performs an `await` for some async operation.  Hooks aren't intended to allow manipulation, only to give access to the stages.

Still, you *can* delay the app just by not loading it until the store action completes, but realize this means a blank page for the user, which is a bad user experience.  But here's how you can do that:

***main.js***

```js
const preload = async () => {
  await store.dispatch('config/get');    // `await` store action which returns a promise
  
  new Vue({
    store,
    router,
    render: (h) => h(App)
  }).$mount("#app");
}

preload();
console.log('LOADING...');
```

---

#### The better way

It's better to dispatch the action and *not* wait for it.  Let *App.vue* load and use `v-if` to show a splash screen until some store state `isLoading` is `false`:

***main.js***

```js
store.dispatch('config/get');

new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

***App.vue***

```js
<template>
<div>
  <div v-if="isLoading">
    LOADING...     <!-- Attractive splash screen here -->
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <router-view></router-view>  <!-- Don't show the router view until ready -->
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Remove the navigation guard completely and in *App.vue*, put a watch on `isLoading`.  Once it's no longer loading, redirect based on the state of the account getter:

```js
computed: {
  ...mapState(['isLoading'])
},
methods: {
  redirect() {
    const path = this.$route.path;
    if (!this.$store.getters["config/isConfigured"]) {
      path !== '/setup' && this.$router.push({ path: '/setup' });
    } else {
      path !== '/' && this.$router.push({ path: '/' });
    }
  }
},
watch: {
  isLoading(val) {
    if (val === false) {
      this.redirect();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Unfortunately I can't get it to work. As soon as `loading ` becomes `false`, I get redirected to `/setup`. The watcher seems redundant. It throws an error "duplicate navigation".

Comment: You can check the current route via `to.path` (in guard) or `this.$route.path` (in component) to avoid redundant routing.  Your `beforeEach` arguments are wrong too btw, it's `(to, from, next)`.  There are variations to this answer that might be better for whatever you're after.  You can remove the navigation guard or remove the watch.  You could remove the watch and only check `isLoading` in the guard-- redirecting to `/setup` if the app is still loading.

Answer (score 1):

These lifecycle callbacks have synchronous behaviour.
what you can do is something like

```
store.dispatch("config/get").then(() => {

  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {...}

  new Vue({...})

})
```

or you can call it in beforeEach of router and store some state like isLoaded and call store.dispatch only once on firstCall and for the rest of call use stored state